# tabla simple con conteo total para cada especie en R

Tags: r, rstudio, group-by, aggregate, summarise

Tengo un dataset de especie, # de insectos en ala, #insectos en pierna, etc. Solo quiero una tabla que me haga una suma total por especie por cada variable hasta ahora intenté usar `aggregate` y `summarise` y `vtable` (esta ultima sí funcionó pero me salen las especies en el titulo de cada columna y quiero que sea al revés, o sea que vaya en cada fila)

Esto funcionó

```
st(sqshbmts)
st(sqshbmts, group = "Id", group.test = TRUE)
```

Cuando intento con `summarise` y `aggregate` no sé que estoy haciendo mal:

Con aggregate el código corre pero no obtengo nada

```
aggregate(sqshbmts, by=list(sqshbmts$Id), FUN = length()
```

Con `summarise` solo estoy usando una variable, no sé cómo aumentar mi cantidad de variables como #insectos en pierna, o torax...

```
group_by(sqshbmts$Id) %>% 
    summarise(sqshbmts$wing=mean(sqshbmts$wing, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Con respecto al `agreggate`, revisa como escribiste el código por que hay un error tipográfico, además estas usando `length` ¿no debería ser `mean`? por otro lado dudo que no retorne información, a menos que se trate de un `data.frame` vacio. O sea, por el lado del `agreggate` falta información en la pregunta como para responderte. Por el lado de `dplyr`  tienes el verbo `summarise_all()`y podrías hacer algo así: `sqshbmts %>% group_by(Id) %>% summarise_all(mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Ah, y me olvidaba.. Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Con las funciones de `dplyr` se recomienda unirlas con pipes (`%>%`), comenzando desde el objeto y luego llamando las columnas sin llamar nuevamente al objeto:

```
sqshbmts %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(wing = mean(wing, na.rm = TRUE))
```

También, ya que mencionas que son múltiples columnas, puedes aplicar una función a varias o todas (en este ejemplo a todas menos `Id`):

```
sqshbmts %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), 
                   ~mean(.)))
```